# Can a WinUI-3 app run smoothly on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: .net, winui-3

We are looking at building an WinUI-3 app, as the target client machine is Windows 10 (v1909 and above). However some clients need to use it on Windows Server 2016 as well.

Will the WinUI-3 app run without any hiccups on Windows Server 2016. The documentation of WinUI seems a little hazy about the supported Windows Server Versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. As Windows Server 2016 is still supported there are many customers using them. Unfortunately its core equals Windows 10 version 1607 and [WinUI 3 is supported at versions 1809+](https://microsoft.github.io/microsoft-ui-xaml/about.html)